# Numerical wildcard for jdbc prepareStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I´m doing a query with a prepareStatement in JDBC. I would sometimes insert a "numerical woldcard" instead of an actual number.

**Consider a query like this:**
Domains: a int, b text;

```
pStatement = 
    dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM R1 WHERE a LIKE ? AND b LIKE ?");
```

**Some times I would like to:**

```
pStatement.setInt(1, 10);
pStatement.setString(2,"%");
pStatement.exequteQuery();
```

That is no problem, since the wildcard is a string.

**Other times I would like to:**

```
pStatement.setInt(1, ANY_INT_SHOULD_BE_VALID);
pStatement.setString(2, "Hello");
pStatement.exequteQuery();
```

That does not work. I could change the query and use i.e. "a <> 0" but that requires extra code and makes the use of a prepareStatement somewhat unnecessary.

Is there a way to solve this *without changing the actual query*, only the inserted values?

Comment: is **ANY_INT_SHOULD_BE_VALID** a variable name ??

Comment: No, ANY_INT_SHOULD_BE_VALID is a description of how the position should be used. I.e. the "numeric wildcard". If you know a better way of expressing that please feel free to tell me.

Comment: what do you mean by "numeric wildcard"?? some thing like string rep of a number ?

Comment: I would like to make a prepareStatement where one int sometimes could be exchanged with the equivalent of a wildcard used in String contexts. That is searching for any number as a wildcard lets yu search for any string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could change the query and use i.e. "a <> 0"

For your requirement, this should be `a IS NOT NULL`.

> but that requires extra code and makes the use of a prepareStatement somewhat unnecessary.

PreparedStatement is necessary for the VARCHAR column the most and that seems to be present in all scenarios.

> pStatement.setString(2,"%");

This wouldn't match all the strings as `LIKE` operator is needed for `%` to take its special meaning.

> Is there a way to solve this without changing the actual query, only the inserted values?

No, IMO, since the requirements are fundamentally different, you would need to have queries accordingly.

Comment: Oh I did mean "LIKE" not "=". Just sloppy of me.

Comment: But could you please explain why the queries are fundamentally different? As I understand they are quite similar.

Comment: For me, the column `a` being just set is different from set to a specific value. Same argument applies to varchar column equal to something specified vs like something. A query generated with LIKE operator and no wildcard characters sounds somewhat incorrect. And so the "IMO".